# DCOM server debug

Tags: c++, atl

I'm learning DCOM and I need to debug a class that I have created, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [DebugBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679297(VS.85).aspx) could be of great help for this. You just need to add a conditional compilation line in the debug build to allow execution of this line and the debugger will start. The other way is attaching the debugger to the process and set a breakpoint in the process..

Comment: try this tool too ATLTraceTool : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khbh432d(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Write a simplest client that does CoInitialize(), then CoCreateInstance().

Insert delays (call to Sleep() for example) into DllGetClassObject() of your server - with ATL you have the full source.

After the client calls CoCreateInstance() attach the debugger to the server host process.